# Angular2: Issues with navbar trying to route to non-existent child views when placing it in individual views instead of app.component.ts

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I am busy with an Angular2 web app where I very recently implemented a login component...  I have a a navigation Component which is a bootStrap navbar, before I added the login component to my app I had the NavigationComponent in my app.component.ts template which worked perfectly as I could have the different views inserted below the navbar.  With my new login component I removed the navigation component from app.component.ts and added it to all my views separately   I now have an issue where when navigating to another view it tries to navigate to a child view of the current view which doesn't exist e.g. when navigating from home to settings the angular router tries to navigate to 'home/settings' where it should just be 'settings'...  Any idea what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

What solved it for me:

As I moved the navigation component directives one folder down I had to pass the folder above to the router...
In my navigation component instead of navigating to [''] I changed it to navigate to ['../']